# Is it possible to prevent portion of page from google to index

Tags: html, indexing, google-index

I am working on ruby on rails application.
In one of my page I want to prevent portion of page to get indexed by google.
Is it possible to prevent portion of page from google to index?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the googleon/googleoff tags

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
don't index this content
<!--googleon: index-->
```

Comment: Thanks for such a fast reply, Let me try

Comment: HI Puneet, I have added my content in betwenn googleoff and googleon tags, still it is getting indexed

Comment: this only works for Google Appliances and is irrelevant for the public Google crawler.